# Why England cricket stadium have slope boundaries?

Tags: cricket

I mean Boundaries look little high, I watched so many matches played in
England, I notice this thing very easily.

I am thinking It can found in **Lords Cricket stadium.**

Is there any reason for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lord's slope is a historical anomaly - it's been there since the ground moved to its current location in 1814. Nobody would build a cricket ground with that kind of slope these days, and if they did, nobody would let Test cricket be played there.

But Lord's is Lord's. It's "the home of cricket" and it's impossible to change now.